# onRatingChanged not working properly

Tags: android, ratingbar

When the RatingBar in my application is changed, I want it to be able to change a text view (a tip value) to certain numbers depending on the current RatingBar value. I have tried this by using the onRatingChanged method, but that doesn't seem to be working. Also, I want the tip value to change based on the RatingBar value, even if the user doesn't touch the ratingbar, because there is a quiz section on my app that changes the ratingbar. I'm sorry if this isn't very clear, it's hard to explain.

**What I want:**

1. When the user changes the rating bar, change the tip value accordingly, ex. 5 stars -> 20 tip value
2. When the ratingbar changes (because the user uses the quiz activity) change the tip value accordingly

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.tipquiz;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRatingBarChangeListener {

    // Testing Stuff to show the rating value, will need to use later for maths
    static RatingBar rb;
    TextView tipsTV;

    private AdView adview;

    ImageView greyPlus, greyMinus, greyPlus2, greyMinus2;

    TextView peopleDiningTV, peopleDiningTitle;
    float peopleDining = 2;

    TextView tipValue;
    float tipValueFloat = 10;

    TextView subtotal, total;
    TextView subtotalTitle, totalTitle;

    TextView epp, eppTitle;
    Button done;
    ImageView settingsButton;

    // Elements for hiding and such
    static RelativeLayout rl;

    public static int rating = 3;

    // The Image used as the DropDown button, Rotate code below
    ImageView dropDownButton;

    Boolean hasRotated = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dropDownButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dropDownButton);
        rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        rb.setRating(rating);

        tipsTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        tipValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipText);

        greyPlus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greyPlus);
        greyMinus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greyMinus);

        greyPlus2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greyPlus2);
        greyMinus2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greyMinus2);

        peopleDiningTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPeople);
        peopleDiningTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

        subtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtotalText);
        subtotalTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtotalTitle);

        total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalText);
        totalTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTitle);

        epp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eppText);
        eppTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eppTitle);

        done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);
        settingsButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);

        greyPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tipValueFloat++;
                tipValue.setText(tipValueFloat + "%");
            }
        });
        greyMinus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (tipValueFloat >= 1) {
                    tipValueFloat--;
                    tipValue.setText(tipValueFloat + "%");
                }
                if (tipValueFloat == 0) {
                    tipValue.setText("No Tip.");
                }
            }
        });

        greyPlus2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                peopleDining++;
                peopleDiningTV.setText(peopleDining + "");
            }
        });
        greyMinus2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (peopleDining > 1) {
                    peopleDining--;
                    peopleDiningTV.setText(peopleDining + "");
                }
            }
        });

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    QuizFragment qf = new QuizFragment();

    public void dropDown(View view) {
        if (hasRotated == false) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                    android.R.animator.fade_out);
            dropDownButton.setRotation(90);
            ft.add(R.id.quizFragment, qf);
            ft.show(qf);
            ft.commit();
            hasRotated = true;

            // Hiding Elements, so they don't show through the fragment
            tipsTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            greyPlus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            greyMinus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tipValue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            greyPlus2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            greyMinus2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            peopleDiningTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            peopleDiningTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            subtotal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            subtotalTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            total.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            totalTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            epp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            eppTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            done.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            settingsButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (hasRotated == true) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_out,
                    android.R.animator.fade_out);
            dropDownButton.setRotation(0);
            hasRotated = false;
            ft.remove(qf);
            ft.commit();

            // Hiding Elements, so they don't show through the fragment
            tipsTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            greyPlus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            greyMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tipValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            greyPlus2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            greyMinus2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            peopleDiningTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            peopleDiningTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            subtotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            subtotalTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            total.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            totalTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            epp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            eppTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            done.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            settingsButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void openSettings(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
            boolean fromTouch) {
        if(ratingBar.getRating() == 5){
            tipValue.setText(20+"");
        }
    }

    public void done(View view) {
        float subtotalCost = Float.parseFloat(subtotal.getText().toString());
        float tip = tipValueFloat / 100;
        float totalCost = (subtotalCost * tip) + subtotalCost;

        epp.setText(totalCost / peopleDining + "");

        total.setText(totalCost + "");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set any ratingBarChangeListener for your rating bar.
You can do that like this(add this in onCreate() method):

```
rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // Do what you want
            if(rating == 5){
                tipValue.setText(20+"");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: does this go in onCreate?

Comment: Yes, in onCreate. you can add this code-part right after initializing the ratingbar (rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);)

Comment: Weirdly, I'm getting a nullPointerError for some reason, if I have more than 2 conditions:    if (rating == 5) {
     tipValue.setText(20.0 + "%");
     tipValueFloat = 20;
    }else if(rating == 4){
     tipValue.setText(15.0 + "%");
     tipValueFloat = 15;
    }
    else if(rating == 3){
     tipValue.setText(10.0 + "%");
     tipValueFloat = 10;
    }else if(rating == 2){
     tipValue.setText(5.0 + "%");
     tipValueFloat = 5;
    }else if(rating == 1){
     tipValue.setText(0.0 + "%");
     tipValueFloat = 0;
    }   Error on line 77 ( tipValue.setText(10.0...

Comment: Oh sorry before this method you should initialize your `TextView` I mean `tipValue`.